# How to remove a property from a spring bean

Tags: java, spring

I want to remove a property from a spring bean,
this property may be an object or java primitive-ish type(String,int,map..)

```
<bean id="test" class="me.test.xxxx">
       <property name="user" ref="me.test.user"/>
       <property name="other" ref="me.test.other"/>
</bean>
```

I create a new class to implement `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and override `PostProcessBeanFactory`

I will delete all beans I don't want at this method, but I don't know how to delete an object property from a bean property.

thanks.

Comment: delete beans and delete object property does not seem clear enough, you can redefine object properties in the methods where you don't want to use the injected properties

Comment: What do you mean by "delete" a bean property? Set its value to `null` / default values or actually remove the property from the bean (bytecode manipulation?)

Comment: Seems like an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please clarify the purpose of what you are doing.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly yes ,remove the property from the bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to achieve, but if you want to remove, for example,

```
   <property name="other" ref="me.test.other"/>
```

before the bean is initialized, declare a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` bean in your context with the following implementation

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("test"); // get the bean definition in some way
    if (beanDefinition != null) {
        beanDefinition.getPropertyValues().removePropertyValue("other"); // remove the property value based on some criterion
    }
}
```